# Listing methods implemented in a Rails 5 model. Exclude accessors and callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Is there a way to list all class and instance methods (separately) that are **implemented** in a Rails 5 model, while excluding inherited methods, methods provided by mixins, attribute accessors, ActiveRecord callbacks and any other methods that were not explicitly implemented in the model? In other words, if there is no `def some_method` statement within the model file, then `some_method` should not be listed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For the class methods:

```
module_methods = Model.included_modules.map(&:methods)
Model.methods - Model.superclass.methods - module_methods
```

For some model Model.  And you can use `instance_methods` for the instance methods.

Comment: Both solutions (for class and instance methods) include callbacks such as `before_add_for_*` and `before_remove_for_*`. Any idea on how to remove those?